# Regex that excludes certain words

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-negation

I need a **regex** that grabs the first `n` characters from a word excluding `The` and `A`.

For example, here is my sample dataset:

```
The firstMatch
A SecondMatch
the thirdMatch
a Fourthmatch
```

Here is the regex that I tried: `"^(.{3}).*$`

That grabs the first three characters of each of the input strings. But what I really want is the first three characters of each input string *not* including `A` or `The`

So, for the above input strings the matches I want are:

```
'fir', 'Sec, 'thi', 'Fou'
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: @zx81 Doesn't really matter, about all languages nowadays are using PCRE anyway.

Comment: @MightyPork You're kidding, right? Let's see, who uses PCRE... PHP, R... But not Java, C# and other .NET languages, Python, Ruby, Scala, JavaScript etc. See my answer for different solutions for different languages.

Comment: The basic syntax is the same

Comment: @MightyPork "_basic syntax_"... Whoa. At least lookarounds aren't necessarily present on non-PCRE engines.

Comment: @MightyPork So you agree that they're not all using `PCRE`? But if  `The basic syntax is the same`, why does my answer need three flavors to account for differences in syntax?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on which regex engine you are using (originally the question wasn't tagged `Ruby`, so I'll leave the other options.)

**Option 1: Lookbehind (C#, PHP, Java)**

```
(?im)(?<=^The |^a )\w{3}
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/49).

Many engines support lookbehind, but not many support lookbehinds of variable width.

**Option 2: `\K` (PHP, Perl, Ruby 2+)**

```
(?im)^(?:The |a )\K\w{3}
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/50).

The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns

**Option 3: Capture Group (JavaScript, Python, others)**

```
(?im)^(?:The |a )(\w{3})
```

In [the demo](http://regex101.com/r/fQ1iD5/51), look at the Group 1 capture in the right pane.

The parentheses capture the match to Group 1. We retrieve it from Group 1.

**Explanation**

- `(?i)` turns on case-insensitivity line
- `(?m)` turns on multi-line mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match on each line
- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `(?<=^The |^a )` is a lookbehind that asserts that what precedes the current position is the beginning of the string and `The`, or the beginning of the string then `a`
- `(?:The |a )` is a non-capturing group with an OR `|` alternation inside
- the parentheses in `(\w{3})` capture the match to Group 1.

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
^(?:(?:the|a)\s+)?(.{3})
```

using case insensitive search.

The `.*$` part in your original regex is pointless.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
^(the|A)? *(.{3}).+$
```

catching group 2, being sure to use multi-line, global and insensitive modifiers

next time I suggest you to specify the regex compiler you are using